# Java Regex: find a match only at the beginnings of words

Tags: java, regex

For example, I have a set of the strings:

```
"Abc zcf",
"Abcd zcf",
"Zcf Abc",
"Zcf Abcd",
"Test ez",
"Rabc Jabc"
```

How to find in this set strings which any word begin at "abc" characters?
In my example it would be strings

```
"Abc zcf",
"Zcf Abc",
"Abcd zcf",
"Zcf Abcd"
```

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match anything, followed by a word boundary, followed by `abc`. You also want to do this in a case-insensitive way. The pattern

```
(?i).*\\babc.*
```

Will work. A quick example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\babc.*");

    final String[] in = {
        "Abc zcf",
        "Abcd zcf",
        "Zcf Abc",
        "Zcf Abcd",
        "Test ez",
        "Rabc Jabc"};

    for (final String s : in) {
        final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Abc zcf
Abcd zcf
Zcf Abc
Zcf Abcd
```

**EDIT**

Further to @fge's comments about matching the whole pattern here is a neater way of searching for the pattern in the `String`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?<=\\b)abc");

    final String[] in = {
        "Abc zcf",
        "Abcd zcf",
        "Zcf Abc",
        "Zcf Abcd",
        "Test ez",
        "Rabc Jabc"};

    for (final String s : in) {
        final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

This says find `abc` that *is preceded by* `\b` - i.e. the word boundary. The output is the same.

Comment: The problem here is that you try and match the whole input. And in this case this is not needed.

Comment: @fge I think this problem is defined in a way that it makes more sense to try and match the whole input. Obviously you could drop the `.*` and use `find()` but I think it's clearer if you define a pattern that matches the whole input.

Comment: Well, I personally disagree. Matching the whole input is losing 90+% of regular expressions' power... This is why regexes in XML suck.

Comment: You don't need to put the word boundary into a lookbehind assertion.`\\b` at the required position is just fine.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use a `Pattern`:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bAbc");

// ...

if (p.matcher(input).find())
    // match
```

FYI, `\b` is the word anchor. Java's definition for a word character is the underscore, a digit or a letter.

Comment: You should probably note that Java defines a word as anything consisting of letters, digits and underscores.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
if( maChaine.startWith("Abc") ) 
{ 

    list.add( maChaine ) ; 
}
```

Comment: `|| maChaine.contains(" Abc")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex for your problem:

```
(^Abc| Abc)
```